# Prevent exposure to class while getting an interface

Tags: c++, interface

I made the example that is shown in below figure analogue to a real project that I am working on. I'm implementing this project in C++.

The main point of this example is that I have a `FruitGarden` of which I know that it always contains a single `AppleTree`. In `FruitGarden`'s function `StartHarvesting`, a check should be done whether the `AppleTree` is ready for harvesting. For this purpose, I created an interface class.

The way that I'm using the interface now is by implementing a function `GetTreePointer` in `Vegitation` and casting it to an `IFoodTree` (and checking for NULL). The problem that I see in this is that I am exposing my full Tree to the outside world (by implementing the `GetTreePointer`), enabling the call of other public functions which are not intended for use outside `Vegitation`.

My main question is: What is the best way to get the interface `IFoodTree` which is pointing to the `AppleTree`?

[image: UML diagram]

Comment: Edited to make it more readable, but since I can't update the UML I've left the "Vegitation" (=> Vegetation).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not provide `GetTreePointer()` in `Vegitation`, which may be used in `Garden` to check whether it is OK to harvest.

In order to get the apples, in `Vegitation`, `bool canHarvest()` helps to check whether it is the right time to harvest apples, and `vector<Apple> harvest()` to get the fruits. By doing so, it will not expose `Tree` outside Vegitation.

Another way to achieve that is to put `Vegitation` as an inner protected class of `Garden`.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options here. The easiest may be `virtual bool Vegetations::ReadyForHarvest() const { return false; }`.

Another easy one is to keep private functions `private`. If `AppleTree::Foo` is only intended to be callable from `Vegetation`, `Vegetation` should have defined `private: virtual void Foo() = 0;`. It's pretty clear that `Vegetation` should not know about derived classes, that's reversing the direction of inheritance and far too fragile. Instead derived classes must implement what the base class demands, in terms of pure virtual functions. The compiler helps you with this.